# How to reduce file permissions without removing using powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have the following script to remove access rules to a file:

```
$acl = Get-ACL $file
$rules = $acl.access | Where-Object { 
    $_.FileSystemRights -like "FullControl" -or $_.FileSystemRights -like "ReadAndExecute")
}
foreach ($accessRule in $rules) {
  $acl.RemoveAccessRule($rule)
}

Set-Acl  $acl
```

However, I want to downgrade access for some accounts and not remove all permissions completely. For example, removing FullControl, but still allowing some other permissions. Is there a way I can remove only some permissions and leave the rest of the rule as it is?

Comment: `RemoveAccessRule` removes **all** matching allow or deny permissions.  I guess you need to further specify which rules exactly need to be removed and/or later need to be added to the ACL. You can use [RemoveAccessRuleSpecific](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemsecurity.removeaccessrulespecific) for that, which will remove only **a single** matching allow or deny rule.

Comment: You'll need to add a new corresponding access rule with the chosen subset of rights

Comment: I want the rule to retain the rights it already had except for the permissions I want to remove. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Consider using `icacls` to tweak file permissions. While not "pure PowerShell", it's vastly easier to use safely than twiddling ACLs explicitly.